# Object Can't Reference Instance Object Error - IIS 6.0 SQL Server 2000

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, windows, iis

Here is the error I get when going to a website on the IIS v6.0 server that is running SQL Server 2000, which I'm hosting. I have moved this server from another location and so I'm wondering if it can't find the database. What do you recommend? thanks

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 38:     {
Line 39:         ds = dbCat.Getcategories();
Line 40:         DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
Line 41:         dr["id"] = "0";
Line 42:         dr["name"] = "All";

Source File: c:\webapps\pbxc.new-web.09302009\PBXC_Updated_\Website\support.aspx.cs    Line: 40 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   support.loadCategories() in c:\webapps\pbxc.new-web.09302009\PBXC_Updated_\Website\support.aspx.cs:40
   support.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\webapps\pbxc.new-web.09302009\PBXC_Updated_\Website\support.aspx.cs:25
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

Comment: Based on the stack trace, either `ds` or `Tables` is null.  Perhaps `dbCat.GetCategories()` didn't return anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the project then you should be able to put a break point in on line 40 of the support.aspx.cs file and see whether dbCat.Getcategories() actually returns something. If it it can be null then you should have a conditional statement to check for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below snippet after ds= dbCat.Getcategories()

```
  if (ds !=null)
    {
    //your code
    }
    else    
    {
    }
```